# IQueryable to List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I know IQueryable yields no result but just an expression builder, my problem is how can actually use it to execute query and return the set as List to be able to bind it on a grid.

```
  IQueryable query = _campaignManager.GetCampaign(filter, values);

  // this line returns error
  List<Campaign> campaigns = query.Cast<Campaign>().ToList();

  grdCampaigns.DataSource = campaigns;
  grdCampaigns.DataBind();
```

additional details: GetCampaign()

```
    public IQueryable GetCampaign(string filter, params object[] values)
    {
        string parameters = string.Empty;
        foreach (object obj in values)
        {
            parameters += obj.ToString() + ",";
        }

        parameters.Remove(parameters.Count() - 1, 1);

        var query = context.Campaigns.Where(filter, parameters)
           .Select("new(CampaignID,CampaignName)");

        return query;
    }
```

I'm using [DynamicQueryable](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for dynamic linq queries

The .Select Extension method of the DynamicQueryable

```
     public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, selector, values);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Select",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType, lambda.Body.Type },
                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
    }
```

IQueryable .Where() extension

```
       public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
        LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, typeof(bool), predicate, values);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
    }
```

thanks...

Comment: Im using entity framework 4, error: Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'Campaign'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: note: 'Campaign' is the generated entity of the EF context

Comment: you should let us look at `GetCampaign()`. Can't imaging where `DynamicClass1` comes from. For sure this cast is invalid.

Comment: I think the new Type[] returns the DynamicClass1 type... im not sure

Comment: @dotnetlinc Did you ever solve this problem I'm having a similar issue, I just need to cast to any iEnumberable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IQueryable can be of type T e.g.
IQueryable query=+CampaignManager.GetCampaign

but since you are using IQueryable you can use

```
var enumerator= c.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
             //add these records to some collection say Collection or Campaign or Create any entity with Name and Id and then assign that collection to DataSource    
            }
```

i have tried that it's working you can proceed wit it.

Comment: your are returning a dynamic Class through new{CampaignID,CampaignName} that's why it's throwing invalid cast operation... 
one option is to translate it by yourself through reflection or by loop..

Comment: how can I make it return Campaign object? new Campaign(CampaignID,CampaignName)?

Comment: if you are using 3.0 or later then why don't you do something like this:
var campaigns = query..ToList();  
grdCampaigns.DataSource = campaigns;

var will work as Dynamic variable type and it will allow you to bind DynamicClass  and in your binding you can still use the two properties you are already using

Comment: `var campaigns = query.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();` <- still throws error `Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.` Im using 4.0.. thanks

Comment: @dotnetlinc 
var campaigns = query.ToList(); 
don't use Cast in that Simply query.ToList();

Comment: but theres no ToList() method in IQueryable (Not Iqueryable<T>)

Comment: since you are using IQueryable you can use
var enumerator= c.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
             //add these records to some collection say Collection or Campaign or Create any entity with Name and Id and then assign that collection to DataSource    
            }

i have tried that it's working you can proceed wit it.

Answer (score 2):

With .NET 4.0 and a slight modification to the Dynamic library, we can achieve the expected result for: `var campaigns = query.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();` or even `var campaigns = query.ToList();`

Here is how to do it:
Change:

```
public abstract class DynamicClass {
```

to:

```
public abstract class DynamicClass : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject {
```

Here is a working code using the modified library:

```
var query = db.Customers.Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
            OrderBy("CompanyName").
            Select("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");

foreach (var val in query.Cast<dynamic>().ToList())
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, Phone: {1}", val.Name, val.Phone));
```

We may also add an overloaded extension method to the [DynamicQueryable](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) class:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Select<T>(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
{
    return Select(source, selector, values).Cast<T>();
}
```

Then we should be able to call like this:

```
var query = db.Customers.Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
            OrderBy("CompanyName").
            Select<dynamic>("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");

foreach (var val in query.ToList())
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}, Phone: {1}", val.Name, val.Phone));
```

P.S: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

> Any object can be converted to dynamic type implicitly.

So we should be able to call `Cast<dynamic>()` without the proposed change.